# No Audio on LG Viper Phone

Tags: audio, lg

I have a LG Viper (LG-LS840). There is no audio output on this phone. I can make and receive calls but there is no audio on either end. I can not hear music, alarms or phone calls. I cannot hear any audio through my headset either. I went to settings.., sound Profile is set to sound. Quiet Time is not selected. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I contacted AVG's new troubleshooting team.   The Tech said he only knows one thing I can try.  He said to take battery out an hold down the power button for 15 to 20 seconds.  It worked....    Now it will work unless you turn on the speaker. If you turn on the hands free speaker you will lose voice again and have to do it over again.    Other than that he said to contact your carrier for problem solving it. It worked for me so I am all set sound to and from callers work on my Viper LS840 LG lte.